# treeview conditional formatting

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, treeview, conditional-formatting

I have a treeview populating from a data set like this

```
Dim PrSet As New DataSet()
        If lblemail.Text.ToString().Equals("ali.saleem@shakarganj.com.pk") Then
            PrSet = PDataset("select distinct PEND,to_char(BPV_DTE,'DD MON YYYY') BPV_DTE,BPV_DTE BPV_DTE1,COUNT from chq_dir order by 3 desc")
        Else
            PrSet = PDataset("select distinct PEND,to_char(BPV_DTE,'DD MON YYYY') BPV_DTE,BPV_DTE BPV_DTE1,COUNT from chq_dte order by 3 desc")
        End If
        TreeView2.Nodes.Clear()
        For Each dr As DataRow In PrSet.Tables(0).Rows
            Dim tnParent As New TreeNode()
            tnParent.Text = dr("PEND").ToString()
            tnParent.Value = dr("BPV_DTE")
            tnParent.PopulateOnDemand = True
            tnParent.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Select
            tnParent.ToolTip = tnParent.Text
            tnParent.Expand()
            TreeView2.Nodes.Add(tnParent)
            If dr("COUNT").ToString() = "0" Then
                TreeView2.Font.Bold= True
            End If
        Next dr
```

There is Column `COUNT` in which there is `0` in some dates.Problem is that i am trying to bold the treeview where `COUNT` is `0` but it is not working Any one can give me clear idea to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved My Question Like this

```
 If Not dr("COUNT") = 0 Then
 tnParent.Text = "<b>" & dr("PEND").ToString() & "</b>"
 End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply the style to `tnparent` and do this before adding the node to parent in treeview, and also from your code it looks like you are changing the fonts to italic not bold.

Comment: But sir there is no font property for tnparent

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've gethered what you meant by this question...

```
  For Each tn As TreeNode In treeView2.Nodes
     If tn.Text = "0" Then
          Dim index As Integer
          index = tn.Index
          treeView2.Nodes(index).NodeFont = New Font(treeView2.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
     End If
  Next
```

Comment: I have to bold that node where count is `0` u r not telling according to the situation

Comment: Sir I am getting this error `BC30456: 'NodeFont' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode`

Comment: OK i have re written it and now this should be what you are looking for. It does this for each node, and where it is 0, sets the node to bold :)

Comment: Sir Same error on line this line `treeView2.Nodes(index).NodeFont = New Font(treeView2.Font, FontStyle.Bold)`

Comment: OK Ill carry on looking into it